# Is there a more computationally efficient way to find the first occurrence matching a regular expression using Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, findall

Is there a more computationally efficient way in Pandas to get to the final output below? I only want the first occurrence, and it seems computationally inefficient to findall and then get the 0th element of the list, as below:

```
Input:
s= pd.Series(["David Matt Juan Peter David James",
            "Scott David Peter Sam David Ron",
            "Dan Phil David Sam Pedro David Mani"])
s_find= s.str.findall(r'David [A-za-z]*')
print(s_find)

Output:
0    [David Matt, David James]
1     [David Peter, David Ron]
2      [David Sam, David Mani]

Input:
s_find= s_find.str[0]
print(s_find)

Output:
0     David Matt
1    David Peter
2      David Sam
```

Comment: `s.replace(r'^.*?(David \S+).*','\\1',regex=True)` or `s.str.replace(r'^.*?(David \S+).*','\\1',regex=True)` will give you the same result. Although due to backtracking, this might also not be efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` to only take the first match:

```
s.str.extract('(David [A-za-z]*)')
```

This returns:

```
0     David Matt
1    David Peter
2      David Sam
dtype: object
```

Or, avoiding pandas `str` methods, you can use a list comprehension:

```
import re

pd.Series([re.search('(David [A-za-z]*)', i).group() for i in s.values])

0     David Matt
1    David Peter
2      David Sam
dtype: object
```